# Oracle Query doesn't complete

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one query which completes when selecting all columns (using select * from), but it doesn't complete when selecting one column name. I have created necessary indexes. here is my query

```
    SELECT q2.ssn vn_ssn
    --when * here instead of column name then the query completes
    FROM table_0 q2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT ial_t.pin,
        ial_t.serial_number,
        ial_t.surname,
        ial_t.name,
        ial_t.patronymic,
        ial_t.prev_surname
      FROM
        (SELECT pin,
          MAX(serial_number) m_serial_number
        FROM table_1
        GROUP BY pin
        ) ial_m
      INNER JOIN table_1 ial_t
      ON ial_t.serial_number = ial_m.m_serial_number
      ) ial ON q2.pincode    = ial.pin
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 v_q2
    ON V_Q2.VN_TPN     = Q2.TPN
    WHERE v_q2.vn_tpn IS NULL;

** EDIT: **



     1. Plan (Select * from table_name)

            Plan hash value: 2508092269

            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Id  | Operation              | Name             | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                  |   438K|   248M|       |   341K  (1)| 01:08:13 |
            |*  1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER       |                  |   438K|   248M|   193M|   341K  (1)| 01:08:13 |
            |*  2 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER|                  |   438K|   188M|    54M| 19424   (1)| 00:03:54 |
            |   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | VN_Q2            |   439K|    49M|       |  1673   (2)| 00:00:21 |
            |   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | Q2               |   438K|   139M|       |  7889   (1)| 00:01:35 |
            |   5 |   VIEW                 |                  |  6751K|   914M|       |   262K  (1)| 00:52:34 |
            |*  6 |    HASH JOIN           |                  |  6751K|   386M|   122M|   262K  (1)| 00:52:34 |
            |   7 |     VIEW               |                  |  6742K|    45M|       |   134K  (1)| 00:26:55 |
            |   8 |      HASH GROUP BY     |                  |  6742K|   109M|   458M|   134K  (1)| 00:26:55 |
            |   9 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL| IAMAS_ALL_LAST_2 |    10M|   167M|       | 90003   (1)| 00:18:01 |
            |  10 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL  | IAMAS_ALL_LAST_2 |    10M|   521M|       | 90270   (1)| 00:18:04 |
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
            ---------------------------------------------------

               1 - access("Q2"."PINCODE"="IAL"."PIN"(+))
               2 - access("V_Q2"."VN_TPN"(+)="Q2"."TPN")
               6 - access("IAL_T"."SERIAL_NUMBER"="IAL_M"."M_SERIAL_NUMBER")

2. Plan (Select column_name from table_name)

Plan hash value: 1784658367

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                         |     1 |    55 |       |   144K  (1)| 00:28:52 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER            |                         |     1 |    55 |       |   144K  (1)| 00:28:52 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI         |                         |     1 |    51 |  9880K|  9735   (1)| 00:01:57 |
|   3 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN        | VN_Q2_TPN_IDX           |   439K|  4722K|       |   301   (2)| 00:00:04 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL           | Q2                      |   438K|    16M|       |  7867   (1)| 00:01:35 |
|   5 |   VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE        |                         |     1 |     4 |       |   134K  (1)| 00:26:55 |
|*  6 |    HASH JOIN                   |                         |     1 |    32 |       |   134K  (1)| 00:26:55 |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| IAMAS_ALL_LAST_2        |     2 |    50 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IAMAS_ALL_LAST_2_INDEX2 |     2 |       |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |     VIEW                       |                         |  6742K|    45M|       |   134K  (1)| 00:26:55 |
|  10 |      SORT GROUP BY             |                         |  6742K|   109M|   458M|   134K  (1)| 00:26:55 |
|  11 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL        | IAMAS_ALL_LAST_2        |    10M|   167M|       | 90003   (1)| 00:18:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("V_Q2"."VN_TPN"="Q2"."TPN")
   6 - access("IAL_T"."SERIAL_NUMBER"="IAL_M"."M_SERIAL_NUMBER")
   8 - access("IAL_T"."PIN"="Q2"."PINCODE")
```

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error, kindly check the output prompt box (error console window) for the error.
for example SELECT q2.ssn vn_ssn should be q2.ssn as vn_ssn

Comment: Please show *both* queries and their execution plans.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh sorry, I made mistake. I have just  posted the plan.

Comment: You have to post both plans to see the differences

Comment: @dnoeth I have posted both plans.

Comment: I'm not an Oracle guy, but it's easy to see that the second plan is totally different: the optimizer assumes only a single row and the nested loops are very bad for the actual number of rows. Seems to indicate a problem with statistic, you might have to recollet them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the first outer join with an OLAP function:

```
FROM table_0 q2
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
   SELECT *
   FROM
     (
      SELECT ial_t.pin,
        ial_t.serial_number,
        ial_t.surname,
        ial_t.name,
        ial_t.patronymic,
        ial_t.prev_surname,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pin ORDER BY serial_number DESC) AS rn
      FROM table_1
     ) ial_m
    WHERE rn = 1
  ) ial ON q2.pincode = ial.pin
```

And if you don't need to access any rows of this table in your select list you can simply remove this join, it will not change the number of rows returned as it's an outer join.

Comment: @dnoeth Your query contains a syntax error (superfluous ',' before the ORDER BY).

Comment: could you explain me what was the problem?

Comment: @Farid: as i wrote in the other comment, the problem was probably an outdated statistic. The ROW_NUMBER is just the common replacement of the old style MAX subquery for "give me all column of the row with the max/min value". It's usually more efficient.